# how can disable send email automatically in reset password (PasswordResetView) django

Tags: python, django

this is my views.py

```
class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
template_name = 'users/password_reset_form.html'

success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset')

def form_valid(self, form):
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    
    # Check if the user with the provided email exists and is active
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email, is_active=True)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.success(self.request, 'ok.')
        return super().form_valid(form)  # Return the default behavior if user doesn't exist or is inactive
    
    # Generate uidb64 and token
    uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
    token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
    print(email, uidb64, token)
    messages.success(self.request, 'ok.')
    
            
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

path('password_reset/', CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', CustomPasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

]

and this is my settin.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = '*****'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_MODEL = 'users_custom.CustomEmailConfirmation'
```

when i enter email adress for reset password in users/password_reset_form.html , djnafo automatically send email and i can see it in console like :

```
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user     account at http://127.0.0.1:8000.

 Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/reset/MQ/c0exppa87e20490eb2e3c11513cad273efc4cc/

Your username, in case you’ve forgotten: a@a.com

Thanks for using our site!

The http://127.0.0.1:8000 team
```

how can i disable this ?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to disable the automatic email sending in Django**, you can use the EMAIL_BACKEND setting to switch to a dummy backend or an alternative backend that does not send emails. You are currently using the console backend, which still outputs the email to the console.

To disable the email sending, you can use the django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend. Update your settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```

This backend doesn't send real emails but acts as if it does, so you won't see the email in the console anymore.

**But if you want to disable only for this function then,**

```
self.email_backend.send_messages([])
```

add this line inside your form_valid function.

Hope so it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer : must do like this :

```
    class YourPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(
            label=_("Email"),
            max_length=254,
            widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'email'}),
        )
        
        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            # Your custom validation logic for email, if needed
            return email
    
    class CustomPasswordResetView(FormView):
        template_name = 'users/password_reset_form.html'
        form_class = YourPasswordResetForm  # Replace with your custom form
        success_url = '/users/password_reset'  # Replace with your actual success URL
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            
            # Check if the user with the provided email exists and is active
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email, is_active=True)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                messages.success(self.request, 'Password reset instructions will not be sent.')
                return super().form_valid(form)  # Return the default behavior if user doesn't exist or is inactive
            
            # Generate uidb64 and token
            uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
            print(email, uidb64, token)
                    
            return super().form_valid(form)
```